# The function module_invoke returns null?

Tags: 7, search

The function `module_invoke('facetapi','block_view',$delta)` returned the blocks for the search . Then I have ran the apache solr. After that, it returns null. module_invoke returns null after indexing the data in solr. Why module_invoke returns null after running solr? How to debug it?How to fix it

Comment: Why are you sending it three arguments? I believe it only takes two. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21module.inc/function/module_invoke/7

Comment: Wil send the delta also. see the display view blocks in the link . In drupal 6, we wil use 4 args. I tried without The third arg also. But didnt get the results